# Angular TypeError with print operation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, typeerror

I wrote a code where a user can select a printer type from a dropbox and print a content with the selected printer by clicking a button. Whenever I click the print button, it gives a `typeerror` like below. I searched for the problem and I initialized it, but it didn't work. What should I do to fix this error?

[image]

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="50" class="w-100-p py-8">
    <mat-label>Printer Name</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrinter" name="selectedPrinter" [compareWith]="comparePrinter" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of printerList" [value]="prm">
            {{prm.Name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="printSticker()"> Print Sticker </button>
```

TS:

```
public _stickerData: IStickerData = {};
    selectedPrinter: IPrinter = {};
        printerList: IPrinter[];
    selection = new SelectionModel<IStickerData>(true, []);
        printSticker() {
            this.confirmDialogRef = this._dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
                disableClose: false
            });
    
            this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage = 'Do you want to print the sticker?';
    
            this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
                if (result) {
                    this.selection.selected[0].SelectedPrinter = this.selectedPrinter;
                    this._productionService.printStickerData(this._stickerData).subscribe((response: IStickerData) => {
                        this._stickerData = response;
                        this._messages.Show("Printed", "SUCCESS", 3);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.selection.selected[0].SelectedPrinter` is empty , you need to initialize it with at least one object in order to access the array elements and its property.

```
selection = new SelectionModel<IStickerData>(true, []);
```

Above statement creating an empty array of type `IStickerData`, but it is empty.

Probably you need to something like:

```
this.selection.push =new StickerData(this.selectedPrinter);
```

where `StickerData` should be a class that implements IStickerData and must have constructor to pass that string and return a type of `IStickerData` object.

Eg:

```
interface IStickerData{
   SelectedPrinter: string
}

class StickerData implements IStickerData{
   SelectedPrinter = '';
   constructor(item: string){
     this.SelectedPrinter = item;
   }
}
```